# Update Contact Details using Azure AD Graph & Node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Node.js and `azure-graph` to create a user in Azure. It works as expected for basic fields like Name, etc. However, jobTitle and other fields that are usually found in the portal cannot be updated. Any pointers?

[image]

```
  let msRest = require('ms-rest-azure');
  let azureGraph = require('azure-graph');

  let tenantId = common.configDefaults.azure_tenant;
  let clientId = common.configDefaults.azure_client_id;
  let clientPwd = common.configDefaults.azure_client_secret; 

  let create_user_in_azure_ad = function (user, cb) {
    msRest.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, clientPwd, tenantId, {
      tokenAudience: 'graph'
    }, function (err, credentials, subscriptions) {
      if (err) {
        done(err.message, null);
      } else {
        // Create Azure Graph Client to access
        let client = new azureGraph(credentials, tenantId);
        let password = common.generatePassword(10);
        let userParams = {
          accountEnabled: true,
          userPrincipalName: user.email_official, //please add your domain over here
          displayName: user.display_name,
          mailNickname: user.email_official.split("@")[0],
          jobTitle: "A FANCY TITLE",
          passwordProfile: {
            password: password,
            forceChangePasswordNextLogin: true
          },
        };

        // Now, we can create the User in Active Directory
        client.users.create(userParams, function (err, done) {
          if (err) {
            cb(err, null);
          } else {
            // The user is created now with a password. Return this information
            cb(null, {user: user, password: password});
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: `jobTitle` is not created by creating user, it can be done by [updating contact of that user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/contacts-operations#UpdateContact).

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not aware of Node.js, but I think you can create/update `jobTitle` by [updating contact of a specific user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/contacts-operations#UpdateContact).